# does python allows elif statement without else statement?

Tags: python

While teaching python to a friend i tried this statement :

```
val = "hi"
if (val=="hello") or ("w" in val):
    print("hello")    
elif(val=="hi"):
    print("hi")
```

And to my great surprise it worked. I always tought in Python you couldn't do an elif without else.
Has it been always like that or the syntax has changed since a particular version?

Comment: I think it always worked. What you cannot do is use `elif` or `else` without `if` first.

Comment: Did you expect Python to reject executing this code and ask _"or else what?"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`else` is optional, and follows any number of `elif` statements.

From the specification of version 1.6:

```
if_stmt:        "if" expression ":" suite
               ("elif" expression ":" suite)*
               ["else" ":" suite]
```

The `*` in this syntax means zero or more elements, and `[` and `]` means an optional element.

Python 1.6 was the first version released as open source. That said, I'm almost certain it has always been like that, because it is standard among most, if not all, programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked in all versions, just without another case you don't consider the case where `if` and `elif` conditions are not accepted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).